# Execute a terminal command using node.js and capture its output

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute following terminal command to output some doc file:

```
 "02:00:00:04" -s doc > 111.doc
```

Also have to run this through `node.js`:

```
var exec       = require('child_process').exec;
var spawn      = require('child_process').spawn;
var fs         = require('fs');
var workDir = process.env.TSHARK

var args = ['02:00:00:04' ,'-S','doc']
    logStream = fs.createWriteStream(workDir + '//111.doc');

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    child = spawn('tshark', args, {cwd: workDir});

child.stdout.pipe(logStream);
child.stderr.pipe(logStream);

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
child.on('close', function(code) {
    console.log('closing code: ' + code);
});
```

Directly running the terminal command outputs a valid  file

But running the above node script not getting the full  file (last lines are missing).

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: maybe you need to wait for he child to end. You are adding the listeners but not waiting. Try having a setInterval that every 10ms calls himself, and in the on(close) do the proper process.exit(0);

Comment: Take a look at : [How to node : coding-challenges-with-streams](http://howtonode.org/coding-challenges-with-streams) I think you can use exactly the same approach !